# Can't create a multiprocessing Manager when using hydra

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, fb-hydra

I am developing a code where I need to create a Manager to synchronize a Queue. In the project I am using hydra and everything works fine until I create a multiprocessing Manager Object. This is the raised error with *HYDRA_FULL_ERROR=1*:

```
Primary config module 'config' not found.
Check that it's correct and contains an __init__.py file

Set the environment variable HYDRA_FULL_ERROR=1 for a complete stack trace.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mre.py", line 8, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\UX331U\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\hydra\main.py", line 32, in decorated_main
    _run_hydra(
  File "C:\Users\UX331U\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\hydra\_internal\utils.py", line 355, in _run_hydra
    run_and_report(
  File "C:\Users\UX331U\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\hydra\_internal\utils.py", line 207, in run_and_report
    return func()
  File "C:\Users\UX331U\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\hydra\_internal\utils.py", line 356, in <lambda>
    lambda: hydra.run(
  File "C:\Users\UX331U\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\hydra\_internal\hydra.py", line 107, in run
    return run_job(
  File "C:\Users\UX331U\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\hydra\core\utils.py", line 125, in run_job
    ret.return_value = task_function(task_cfg)
  File "mre.py", line 7, in main
    m = Manager()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 57, in Manager
    m.start()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\multiprocessing\managers.py", line 583, in start
    self._address = reader.recv()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 250, in recv
    buf = self._recv_bytes()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 305, in _recv_bytes
    waitres = _winapi.WaitForMultipleObjects(
KeyboardInterrupt
^C
C:\Users\UX331U\Desktop>SET HYDRA_FULL_ERROR=1

C:\Users\UX331U\Desktop>python mre.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 125, in _main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 236, in prepare
    _fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 287, in _fixup_main_from_path
    main_content = runpy.run_path(main_path,
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 265, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 97, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\UX331U\Desktop\mre.py", line 8, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\UX331U\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\hydra\main.py", line 32, in decorated_main
    _run_hydra(
  File "C:\Users\UX331U\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\hydra\_internal\utils.py", line 355, in _run_hydra
    run_and_report(
  File "C:\Users\UX331U\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\hydra\_internal\utils.py", line 210, in run_and_report
    raise ex
  File "C:\Users\UX331U\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\hydra\_internal\utils.py", line 207, in run_and_report
    return func()
  File "C:\Users\UX331U\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\hydra\_internal\utils.py", line 356, in <lambda>
    lambda: hydra.run(
  File "C:\Users\UX331U\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\hydra\_internal\hydra.py", line 100, in run
    cfg = self.compose_config(
  File "C:\Users\UX331U\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\hydra\_internal\hydra.py", line 505, in compose_config
    self.config_loader.ensure_main_config_source_available()
  File "C:\Users\UX331U\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\hydra\_internal\config_loader_impl.py", line 135, in ensure_main_config_source_available
    self.missing_config_error(
  File "C:\Users\UX331U\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\hydra\_internal\config_loader_impl.py", line 109, in missing_config_error
    raise MissingConfigException(
hydra.errors.MissingConfigException: Primary config module 'config' not found.
Check that it's correct and contains an __init__.py file
```

I also attach a minimal code snippet to reproduce the error.

```
import hydra
from multiprocessing import Manager


@hydra.main(config_path='config', config_name='config')
def main(cfg):
    m = Manager()  # The error is in this line
    m.Queue()
main()
```

The config.yaml is correctly created and located since when I don't use the Manager, the entire code works with no errors:

```
- PROJECT ----- config ---- config.yaml
          |
          |
          ----- main.py
```

As far as I have understood, the problem comes from the fact that hydra changes the directory when initialized and afterwards, when the Manager is created, hydra is called again to be initialized but as the directory has been changed, it can not find the config folder. If this is true, is it a bug or can it be solved?

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not able to reproduce the error on my machine.

You can stop hydra from changing directories at runtime by passing [hydra.job.chdir=False](https://hydra.cc/docs/1.2/configure_hydra/job/#hydrajobchdir) at the command line -- see the docs on how to [disable changing current working dir to job's output dir](https://hydra.cc/docs/1.2/tutorials/basic/running_your_app/working_directory/#disable-changing-current-working-dir-to-jobs-output-dir).

```
python main.py hydra.job.chdir=False
```